# Calculating Confidence Interval (STATA code)

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, data-visualization, econometrics, stata

I am having trouble understanding the code that the authors used to calculate the confidence intervals for the whiskers shown in the diagram below. 
[image]

The code that the authors used to calculate the confidence intervals is

```
reg tendtolead public if single == `s' & male == `m', robust
_b[_cons] + _b[public] - 1.96*(_se[public])
_b[_cons] + _b[public] + 1.96*(_se[public]
```

where `tendtolead` is the dependent variable and `public` is the independent variable

However, I used a different method to calculate the confidence intervals and got a different answer:

```
gen hitendtolead = meantendtolead + invttail(n-1,0.025)*(sdtendtolead / sqrt(n))
gen lowtendtolead = meantendtolead - invttail(n-1,0.025)*(sdtendtolead / sqrt(n))
```

I am guessing that this is probably due to the different standard errors. Could anyone explain why the authors used `_se[public]` as the standard error?

Thank you very much.

(The figure is from the paper *‘Acting Wife’: Marriage Market Incentives and Labor Market Investments* by Leonardo Bursztyn, Thomas Fujiwara, and Amanda Pallais (2017))

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the graph appears to be to display the regression results, so it makes sense to use the standard errors from that regression.

Comment: Why did the authors use the standard errors for the independent variable instead of the dependent variable?

Comment: they did not do that, it is the standard error in that model for the dependent variable for that variable.